# How to make qubits more stable towards noise?

Tags: experimental-realization, noise

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3093) and this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0417), the "Noise Stability of Qubits" (the stability of qubits to external noise) has been discussed. In the first one, Gil Kalai states that it is difficult to create a quantum computer since the noise produced in creating a few qubits is enough to reach the threshold for corrupting the entire system of qubits. What can be done to reduce the noise and increase stability of the qubits?

**EDIT**: To clarify the doubts mentioned in  the comments, I want to add that IBM, Rigetti and some other companies have already started manufacturing Quantum Computers with 4-6 qubits. How have they overcome or what are they working on to face this problem of noise sensitivity?

Comment: I've had a brief skim through the papers - the first thing is that they're talking about different types of noise. The reason that I'm VTC-ing is because making qubits more stable depends on both the type of qubit and the *cause* of the noise. If you want to know how to reduce noise caused by magnetic fields on dots (which aren't qubits), that could be an interesting question. If you want to know how to implement a unitary more accurately, that could also be very interesting. Same for wanting to know what causes e.g. decoherence in IBM's systems, but you need to specify what you want to know